# Sorting a list of objects based on a nullable ArrayList attribute of that object using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to sort a list based on a nullable ArrayList in java 8.

List as follows

```
Patient1  visits = [02/15/2010, 02/10/2010]
Patient2  visits = [02/16/2010]
Patient3  visits = [02/17/2010, 02/10/2010]
Patient4  visits = null
```

I am trying to sort the Patient objects based on the descending order of their date of visit (first element in the visits list) using streams sort. The nulls should be placed last. The final result must be

```
Patient3  visits = [02/17/2010, 02/10/2010]
Patient2  visits = [02/16/2010]
Patient1  visits = [02/15/2010, 02/10/2010]
Patient4  visits = null


Patient {
  String name;
  List<Date> visits;
}
```

I have tried the following approach but ends up in null pointer exception even after null check.

```
   list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.nullsLast((Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getVisits() == null ? null : s.getVisits().get(0), Collections.reverseOrder()))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221660/discussion-on-question-by-tester-sorting-a-list-of-objects-based-on-a-nullable-a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that `Comparator.nullsLast` would be used if you had `null` `Patient` objects. This is not your case, because you have `null` visits.

You should use it this way:

```
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
            s -> s.getVisits() == null || s.getVisits().isEmpty() ? 
                 null : 
                 s.getVisits().get(0),
            Comparator.nullsLast(Collections.reverseOrder())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a native Java >= 8 method

```
Collections.sort(/*list name*/visits, /*elements from list*/(l, r) -> /*example logic*/l.date.compareTo(r.date));
```